# Javascript обратное преобразование функции

Tags: javascript

Есть функция

```
prepareMessage = function(e) {
    blockSize = 16;
    e += String.fromCharCode(128);
    var t, r, i = e.length / 4 + 2, s = Math.ceil(i / blockSize), n = [];
    for (t = 0; t < s; t++)
        for (n[t] = [],
        r = 0; r < blockSize; r++)
            n[t][r] = e.charCodeAt(64 * t + 4 * r) << 24 | e.charCodeAt(64 * t + 4 * r + 1) << 16 | e.charCodeAt(64 * t + 4 * r + 2) << 8 | e.charCodeAt(64 * t + 4 * r + 3);
    var a = e.length + 4 * blockSize - 1;
    return n[s - 1][blockSize - 2] = 8 * a / Math.pow(2, 32),
    n[s - 1][blockSize - 2] = Math.floor(n[s - 1][blockSize - 2]),
    n[s - 1][blockSize - 1] = 8 * a & 4294967295,
    n
}
```

результат которой будет

```
prepareMessage('test') = 1952805748,-2147483648,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,544
```

Как мне реализовать функцию так что бы из

> 1952805748,-2147483648,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,544
> вернуть исходное значение
> test

Comment: это из серии как по md5 восстановить текст? :)

Comment: @Zhihar, нет.Это другая серия.

Comment: хороший вопрос для собеседования )